# Predicates of a class are not able to use the instance variable if the class is initialised via Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I am initializing a class via Lombok Builder. Through which I am initializing a variable. But that's variable's value is not available when I use that in a Predicate definition.

My code looks this:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class NumCheck {
    int maxCount;
    Predicate<Integer> isLessThanMax = num -> maxCount < num;
}

public class PredicateInstance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5, b=11;
        NumCheck numCheck = new NumCheck().toBuilder().maxCount(10).build();
        Stream.of(2,5,6,7,10,11,20,32).filter(numCheck.isLessThanMax).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

While debugging, the value of maxCount was not getting initialized to 10. It remained 0.
[image]

If I remove the Lombok builders and do it in normal way, this is working fine:

```
class NumCheck {
    int maxCount;
    Predicate<Integer> isLessThanMax = num -> maxCount < num;
}

public class PredicateInstance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5, b=11;
        NumCheck numCheck = new NumCheck();
        numCheck.maxCount = 10;
        Stream.of(2,5,6,7,10,11,20,32).filter(numCheck.isLessThanMax).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Is it a known limitation of Lombok or am I doing anything wrong here?

**Workarounds that worked but not applicable for my scenario:**

1. Declaring the maxCount as static.
2. Declare BiPredicate and send maxCount along with num parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask yourself whether the `isLessThanMax` should really be settable via the builder. It seems to me more like a constant definition. If that is the case, you should make it `final`. Lombok ignores `final` fields with an initializer when generating the builder.
(You also don't need `@Builder.Default` in this case. However, there is nothing wrong with `@Builder.Default` on fields. There is exactly zero performance or memory impact.)

If you are interested why your code behaves so strange, here's the explanation.
When instantiating using the no-args constructor, `isLessThanMax` is initialized using a reference to the field `maxCount` of this instance. `maxCount` is defaulted to `0`. Then you call `toBuilder()`, which simply copies all values of the instance to the builder. Finally you call `maxCount(10).build()` on that builder. The resulting second instance will have `maxCount = 10`, but exactly the same `isLessThanMax` value than the first instance. That means that the predicate of the second instance still references the field of the first instance, which is `0`. So even though you set `maxCount = 10` for the second instance, the `Predicate` still compares using the `maxCount = 0` value from the first instance.

*tl;dr*: Don't use method references that reference instance fields in combination with `toBuilder()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way that you're invoking the Lombok builder.

Instead of

`NumCheck numCheck = new NumCheck().toBuilder().maxCount(10).build()`;

you should use:

`NumCheck numCheck = NumCheck.builder().maxCount(10).build();`

The former creates an instance using the no-arg constructor, then creates a builder from that, and uses the builder to create a second instance, which is thrown away (not assigned to a variable).

The latter just creates one instance via the builder, and assigns it to the variable.

Comment: This is causing NullPointerException on Predicate. I need to use @Builder.Default on all these functional interfaces and pre-initialized statements. Just to avoid using them, I went with toBuilder approach so these already initialized statements would be proper.